# How do I solve the brain level in G30?

Tags: g30

In chapter 6 of G30, there is a puzzle titled “Brain” which involves unscrambling four sections of a brain.

[image: Beginning state of “brain”]

I’ve been able to unscramble all 4 sections to resemble prices of a brain, but I can’t figure out how to make each piece fit together.

[image: Misaligned brain pieces]

How do I solve the brain level in G30?

Comment: I dont know about the game, but isnt the back of the brain inverted? The purple part should look like the yellow part and vice versa

Comment: @Moacir you are correct. However, I can’t figure out how to rotate those pieces

Comment: I see that on the first image the purple part kinda looks like the blue or green one. Is it possible to keep unscramble even more those pieces so they get rotated?